# User Control Margins

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a UserControl that contains an Ellipse and a few lines.  I have drag and dropped them to position them how I like, but when I use the control on another page, the margins are relative to that page and not the user control so they are way off.  Is there a way to force the margins to be relative to the user control and not he page it's contained in?

Comment: Can you post the XAML - it would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to place them in a `Canvas`, and use `Canvas.Top/Bottom/Left/Right` to position your elements where you'd like.